# Setting up Time.zone in Padrino

Tags: ruby, timezone, padrino

I am having a trouble setting the default ActiveSupport::TimeZone in my padrino project.

In my boot.rb I have

```
Padrino.after_load do
  Time.zone = 'UTC'
  ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = :utc
end
```

My controller file has:

```
MyApp::App.controllers :post do
  get :index do
    puts Time.zone # this returns nil
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

When I hit the index action I get nil for Time.zone. It seems as though something might be overwriting Time.zone or it isn't loaded properly.

- I am able to print out the Timezone after setting it in boot.rb. So I know it was set.

Comment: Hey Moemars, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: no I haven't. in the console it works as suggested below but not in the controller.

Comment: Same for me. Works in tests but not when I run the actual web app in dev  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it like this:

```
Time.zone_default = Time.find_zone!("UTC")
```

That's all you need, but see below for details.

The above worked for me with activesupport 5.0.2. I looked at how `Time.zone` is implemented:

```
class Time
  include DateAndTime::Zones
  class << self
    attr_accessor :zone_default

    # Returns the TimeZone for the current request, if this has been set (via Time.zone=).
    # If <tt>Time.zone</tt> has not been set for the current request, returns the TimeZone specified in <tt>config.time_zone</tt>.
    def zone
      Thread.current[:time_zone] || zone_default
    end
```

I then guessed that it might be missing in the current thread with Padrino.

Presumably `Time.zone` would need to be set once for each thread. For whatever reason, that's not always the case when assigning the zone in `Padrino.before_load`. I did not dig into this, but I'm sure there's a nicer solution to be found that assigns it in each thread.

If you want per-user time zones, not just a global one for the entire app, you will need to dig further.

Answer (score 0):

In my `boot.rb` I've got:

```rb
Padrino.before_load do
  Time.zone = 'UTC'
end
```

and in my `database.rb`:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = :utc
```

Which having tested in the console seems to work:

```
ruby-2.1.4$ padrino c
 => Loading development console (Padrino v.0.12.4)
2.1.4 :001 > Time.zone 
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fbff62ed5c0 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: nil,nil,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: 0,0,UTC>>>> 
2.1.4 :002 > Time.zone.now
 => Tue, 30 Dec 2014 13:14:57 UTC +00:00 
2.1.4 :003 > Time.current
 => Tue, 30 Dec 2014 13:15:01 UTC +00:00 
2.1.4 :004 > ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone
 => :utc
```

N.B. Tested with ruby v2.1.4, padrino v0.12.4, activesupport/activerecord v4.2.0.